# Python Large Excel File error to read cols and row size of file is 90mb

Tags: python

```
import xlrd


def excel_count_row_col(excel_file):
    print(excel_file)
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)
    worksheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

    row_count = worksheet.nrows
    column_count = worksheet.ncols

    total_col_row = row_count * column_count
    print(f"row * column = {total_col_row}")
```

I use python3.7. The error exist is raise BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml'

Answer (score 1):

Modern Office documents (with an extension ending in `x`, like `.docx` and `.xlsx`) are really just zip-files with the actual parts that make up the document.

If you rename the `.xlsx` to `.zip`, you can open the file and have a look at its structure. In the zip, you'll find a folder called `xl/worksheets` and in that a `sheet1.xml`. Apparently, that file either got corrupted, or for a file this size, `xlrd` runs into a problem checking it.

The `Bad CRC-32` indicates that the checksum for the file (a number computed over its contents that should always be the same if the file remains unchanged) no longer matches the file, suggesting file corruption.

Comment: @jmrcas there's not really a solution without knowing more about the problem with the actual file. Have tried loading the file in Excel, making some trivial changes and writing it out as a new `.xlsx`? Also, have you tried loading it, reducing its size by removing most and seeing if that resolves the issue? The problem could be with a specific part of your data, the overall size, or even just this specific file.

Comment: Just wanna ask, how to read in python all the 500,000 rows. because when I open the excel file this show "The data could not be loaded completely because the maximum number of rows per sheet was exceeded." only the 300,000 rows read, when I set     row_count = worksheet.nrows.

Comment: I think you're running into limitations of basic xlrd use with a sheet that size; you may need to consider accessing the data in the .xlsx file directly (for example by opening the zip from Python and accessing the relevant xml using an xml parser like lxml). It's also possible you can push xlrd to read larger files, but the documentation doesn't mention these limits, so you may have to do a bit of hunting in the code and perhaps experiment with files that are just on the cusp of being too large.